# Please show a "more" in the tag search

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-search

When I type windows into the tag bar, it suggests 6 tags - [windows](/questions/tagged/windows), [windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7), [windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8), [windows-xp](/questions/tagged/windows-xp), [windows-8.1](/questions/tagged/windows-8.1) and [windows-vista](/questions/tagged/windows-vista).

[image]

However, Windows 10 has been released, and because currently there are fewer questions (about 1050), it doesn't show up.

Please can there be a "30 more matching tags" at the bottom, to show there are more tags:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

How would the "30 more tags" link work? We don't want the link to send headers, and alter the page's state/position/etc.

I think perhaps Ajax, with arrows each side of the popup box to scroll through the other tags. Then the popup window can remain the same size and same position.

The tags being returned in order of "most questions" does not necessarily reflect *relevance*. And while it's impossible for the site to have any pre-selected *single* display order and it always be relevant for users, I definitely agree being able to even *know* other tags exist is useful, more-so being able to navigate them.

This would perhaps encourage (or help) with users putting appropriate tags on their questions.